# Using different appsetting.json files according solution configuration in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, appsettings, configurationmanager

As I know, for using different appsetting.json files in Visual Studio, `Environment  Variable` is good solution, but I need to something else. I need to do following steps:

1- Select a custom solution configuration like below (for example `Live`):

[image]

2- I have an `appsetting.Live.json` file including my `Live` configuration. So, by selecting `Live`, I need that `appsetting.Live.json` should be used.

I read many articles and SO posts related to this, but no one address my issue. Is there any solution to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set the environment per "configuration" (the dropdown shows configurations), see duplicate.